# I need to replace the female part that a headlight bulb fits into

Tags: headlight, replace, gmc, connector

I don't think the make/model matters here, but just in case, I own a 2009 GMC Acadia.  My driver-side, low-beam headlight went out yesterday.  I bought a replacement H11 bulb and began replacing the bulb.

However, once I got in there, I realized that the small, grey, headlight connector was broken; the part that a headlight bulb normally connects to.  Does anyone know if that is a standard, run-of-the-mill part that I can purchase... Or, better yet, do you think that a typical shop can replace this part?

I'm mainly hoping this isn't a super-specific, dealer-only type of repair.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

H11 Bulb connectors are readily available from Ebay sellers, but will no doubt be available from an automotive shop.  They usually come with short wires fitted, so you will need some way of connecting it to you existing wires after chopping off the old connector.  The best way of doing this is soldering and heat shrinking some insulation.  An alternative to soldering would be using some crimp connectors.  As a last resort, you could use 'chocolate block' style connectors and use insulation tape to insulate it.

Answer (score 2):

The part should be available at any automotive shop.  Alternately, you can check junkyards.  Be sure to cut the wires at about 6" to give you wires to connect to.

Answer (score 1):

Yes any autoparts store should carry what you are looking for.I had the same thing happen to me and I got the replacement piece at Autozone for 7.99.Hope this helps